# Currency converter windows phone 8.1 stuck on WebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, converters, currency

I am trying to make a currency converter for WindowsPhone 8.1. But i got a problem with the WebResponse response =await request.GetResponseAsync().

I want to connect to xe([http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/]) and get the currency from there, but i get this error:

```
( Error 1   The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task').
```

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/T9B58e9z

This is my project for school and it has to be done in 4 weeks and i still can't find a solution. I found an interesting tutorial but it was write in visual basic and i need to write in in c#. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I forgot to add the code: http://pastebin.com/T9B58e9z

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  FYI, you can edit your own answers at any time.  There's no need to append information in comments. :)